# How to remove 2 buttons by pressing one?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to remove the buttons "play" and "help" by pressing just on button "play". How can I do that? I need that the button "play" destroy himself and in addition destroy the button "help"

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from random import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Simon")
window.geometry("300x200")
label = Label(window, text="Simon Game!", font=("Ariel", 80), 
bg="CadetBlue3")
label.pack()
window.configure(bg="CadetBlue3")

def destroy(button):
    def inner():
        button.destroy()
    return inner

def click_help_button():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Instructions", "The device 
creates a series of tones and lights and requires a user to 
repeat the sequence. If the user succeeds, the series becomes 
progressively longer and more complex. Once the user fails, the 
game is over")
help_btn = Button(window, width=12, height=2, text="Help", 
bg="grey",font=("Ariel", 18), command=click_help_button)
help_btn.pack(side='bottom')
help_btn.place(x=800, y=150)


start_btn = Button(window, width=12, height=2, text="Play", 
bg="grey", font=("Ariel", 18), command=destroy(help_btn))
start_btn.pack(pady=10)
start_btn.place(x=525, y=150)
start_btn.config(command=destroy(start_btn))

red_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='red')
red_btn.place(x=495, y=270)
green_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='green')
green_btn.place(x=750, y=270)
blue_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='blue')
blue_btn.place(x=495, y=495)
yellow_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='yellow')
yellow_btn.place(x=750, y=495)

window.mainloop()
```

Thanks to those who help!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the minimal amount of relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a click_play_button function

```
def click_play_button():
    start_btn.destroy()
    help_btn.destroy()
```

And call on it when pressing the play button

```
start_btn = Button(window, width=12, height=2, text="Play",
                   bg="grey", font=("Ariel", 18), command=click_play_button)
start_btn.pack(pady=10)
start_btn.place(x=525, y=150)
```

Below also worked...

```
  def destroy(button):
        button.destroy()
 

def click_help_button():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Instructions", "The device")


help_btn = Button(window, width=12, height=2, text="Help",
                  bg="grey", font=("Ariel", 18), command=click_help_button)
help_btn.pack(side='bottom')
help_btn.place(x=800, y=150)


start_btn = Button(window, width=12, height=2, text="Play",
                   bg="grey", font=("Ariel", 18), command=lambda: [destroy(help_btn), destroy(start_btn)])
start_btn.pack(pady=10)
start_btn.place(x=525, y=150)


red_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='red')
red_btn.place(x=495, y=270)
green_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='green')
green_btn.place(x=750, y=270)
blue_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='blue')
blue_btn.place(x=495, y=495)
yellow_btn = Button(window, width=35, height=15, bg='yellow')
yellow_btn.place(x=750, y=495)

window.mainloop()
```